# react navigation header for StackNavigator screen doesn't render if screen wrapped in HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stack, react-navigation

## Summary

1. I created a custom HOC that checks for a user being authenticated by checking if the redux store has a user.id property
2. I am using react navigation and react native
3. When I wrap my screen component in my HOC, the navigation header appears but is blanked out (and conversely if I DON'T wrap my screen component in my HOC, the navigation header appears properly)
4. There is also react-redux connect in the mix in both the HOC and the wrapped component and I'm wondering if that is making things break

Why is my react navigation header not showing properly when I wrap the screen component in my custom HOC?

I wonder if I'm wrapping things in the wrong order--these are the possibly offending lines of code from the screen component (one or the other is commented out when I'm testing):

```js
// export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EntityPage); <--this renders the header fine

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withAuthentication(EntityPage)); <--this renders the header blank
```

## Code

### Custom HOC I made that checks for authentication

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import {
  connect
} from 'react-redux';

function withAuthentication(Comp) {
  class AuthenticatedScreen extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.user && !this.props.user.id) {
        Alert.alert('you\'re not logged in anymore');
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <Comp { ...this.props
      }
      />;
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      user: state.user,
    };
  }

  AuthenticatedScreen.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.object,
    component: PropTypes.object,
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthenticatedScreen);
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

### Screen component I am wrapping with custom authentication HOC

```js
import withAuthentication from '../User/AuthorizedHOC'; <--my custom HOC import

class EntityPage extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
      return {
        title: 'My Entities',
        headerRight: (
>>        <Button type='action' title='Add New Entity' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('EntityCreate')}>
          </Button>),
        headerStyle: {paddingRight: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : 8},
      };
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.loadEntities();
    }

    render() {
      const {
        entities,
      } = this.props;

      return (
        <FullscreenView>
          <EntityList entities={entities}/>
        </FullscreenView>
      );
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      entities: getSortedEntityList(state),
        };
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      loadEntities: () => dispatch(loadEntities()),
      deleteEntity: (entity) => dispatch(deleteEntity(entity)),
    };
  }

  // export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EntityPage); <--this renders the header fine

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withAuthentication(EntityPage)); <--this renders the header blank
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use [`compose`](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/compose.md) method from redux.
The main utility is

> write deeply nested function transformations without the rightward drift of the code

Since [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#static-properties) expects an original component therefore,

**Usage**

```
import {compose} from "redux"

const composedWithAuthentication = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    withAuthentication
);

const newWithAuth = composedWithAuthentication(EntityPage)

newWithAuth.navigationOptions = {
 // Your Options
}
```

this sets the `navigationOptions` on the outermost `hoc`

or a cleaner way would be to use [hoistStatics](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#hoiststatics) from [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose)

```
export default hoistStatics(composedWithAuthentication)(EntityPage);
```

> Augments a higher-order component so that when used, it copies **non-react static properties** from the **base component** to the **new component**.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and it gave me an error about functions not being valid as a React child. Then I modified the export line to be `export default composedWithAuthentication(ScreenComponent);` The page renders (as it did before) but the react navigation header is still blank

Comment: you sir are a genius! Thank you for your help @Pritish Vaidya

Comment: just a note that if you want to use navigation prop or something else assign a function that returns object to navigationOptions `newWithAuth.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      title: 'My Page',
      headerRight: (
        <Button type='action' title='Add Entity' onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('EntityCreate')}>
        </Button>),
    };
  };`

Comment: Yes, i've also checked out another utility that avoids this.Updated in the answer.

Comment: just updated to use the `hoistStatics` in `recompose` library and it makes things cleaner/easier to read. Don't have to move static navigation declarations down to the bottom of file.